# HTML Table TD 'change' event can't be raised?

Tags: javascript, events

I want to manipulate content in TD with javascript, and when the TD content is changed, I will do something else. But seems the change event never be raise.
The HTML:

```
<table><tr><td id='testTD'>Test</td></tr></table>
```

The javascript:

```
  jQuery().ready(function(){
    jQuery('#testTD').on('change', function(e){alert('td changed');});
    jQuery('#testTD').append('something'); //why this did not raise the 'change' event for td?
  });
```

Any idea?

Comment: how will you change the content of `td`??is it editable??

Comment: using jQuery, like above `jQuery('#testTD').append('something');`

Comment: Why not  `click` event??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to 
>   `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.
>
> *Source:* http://api.jquery.com/change/

If you want to fire a change on other elements, simply call `.change()`

```
jQuery('#testTD').append('something').change();
```

Comment: thanks, that worked! additional question: do we have way to get the old value in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You're heading in the wrong direction here. Change events don't fire on DOM content changes - they fire for changes to the values or states of dropdowns, checkboxes and radio buttons.

There are some non-standard (and wildly browser-inconsistent) events to detect what's called content mutation, but as I say, they're unreliable.

Instead think about a different approach. Instead of attempting to listen directly for content changes, you could use a custom event and trigger it when you change the TD's content.

Comment: do you mean `jQuery('#testTD').append('something').myCustomEvent();`?

Comment: I got it: `jQuery('#testTD').append('somethingelse').trigger('myCustomEvent');`